# what are the relation between CEE and RoCE,iWarp

Tags: rdma

i was trying to have a document about CEE,RoCE,iWarp, RDMA etc..
I searched and find CEE is short for Convergence Enhanced Ethernet, and it includes 802.1Qbb, 802.1Qau, 802.1Qaz standards. Can I look RoCE and iWarp as the realizations of CEE standards, or CEE includes RoCE, iWarp? Another question is what the latest starndards or technologies for RDMA?

Really need help for these information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The more common term now Data Center Bridging (DCB) IEEE 802.1. CEE was an proposal(including several standards) by several companies to improve datacenter networking. They are being (or have been) developed respectively by two separate standards bodies:

- The IEEE Data Center Bridging Task Group of the IEEE 802.1 Working Group
- Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF).

*Convergence Enhanced Ethernet or Converged Enhanced Ethernet (CEE) was defined from 2008 through January 2009 by group of including Broadcom, Brocade Communications Systems, Cisco Systems, Emulex, HP, IBM, Juniper Networks, QLogic*

*Another question is what the latest starndards or technologies for RDMA?*

Latest Standard is RoCEv2 and iWarp